# Fetch UI resource from designer

Tags: codenameone

I was trying quite hard to find in API how to fetch UI resource. I can fetch UI resource names but not actual resources:

```
fetchResourceFile().getUIResourceNames()
```

What I am trying to achieve is, I have designed small component in designer, and I want to add it to form before it's shown.

Is it possible to get UI Component in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most resources you can get using simple getters e.g. `getImage()` etc.

UI elements are more complex since they are bound to the `UIBuilder` class. Our goal when designing this was to keep the binary size very small for developers who don't want the functionality of the GUI builder and so we didn't want to create a dependency from the `Resources` class to the `UIBuilder` class.

So to load a UI component from the designer you need to use the API in reverse:

```
UIBuilder uib = new UIBuilder();
Container cnt = uib.createContainer(resource, name);
```

Notice that since `Form` and `Dialog` are subclasses of `Container` you can naturally downcast to them where appropriate.

Also notice that if you have a `Statemachine` class its a subclass of `UIBuilder` so you won't need to create a new `UIBuilder` instance...

Comment: Currently if I use user-defined container in designer it gets copied instead of being referenced. Would be great if all changes in user-defined container was applied to all instances of that component, otherwise it's potentially error-prone and easy to forget to update component in all locations, plus there is no automated way in designer to find out where user-defined container is used. Currently the only workaround I found is to add these user-defined containers in the code and not in designer..

Comment: It will always be a new instance. The design is for a new instance to be created since the resource file only contains byte data and not instances. If it contained instances you would run out of memory in no time (since icons etc. will all be expanded to bitmaps). The basic design of the GUI builder is to save RAM by discarding instances of forms and recreating them.

Comment: Creating of new instance in runtime makes perfect sense, absolutely. However my question was related to UI builder only. I meant instance of user-defined container in designer mode. IMHO, it should be working more like 'include'. For example, say I have button bar used in two different forms. For simplicity, I would make these included bars not editable in the form builder but only in its own builder. So then new changes applied to button bar, they get populated to forms properly. Instantiation will remain the same as it is.

Comment: Just use findComponentName(...) if you are in the state machine. If you are not just use findByName(...) to find the instance. Its really unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'll explain. I have user-defined container in designer. Initially, I added this container to two forms in designer but then found that it is copied and when I change it, it does not get changed everywhere. That's why I am adding this component in the code. I achieved what I wanted anyway, but all I wanted to say is that it does not sound right that user-defined container cannot be efficiently used in designer.

Comment: Its illegal to add the same components to two containers so doing that wouldn't have worked and thrown an exception anyway. This is the case in Swing and AWT as well and the logic is simple: Component has getParent() hence every component has one parent and no more, so you can't add one container to more than one parent.